# intersection of lines and planes ?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

if 6 lines are drawn in a plane , what is the maximum number of parts in which plane is divided by them ? 
If there are 'k' lines drawn in the plane then plane is divided into how many maximum parts ?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question so far? What is the answer for $k=2$? How about $k=3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line intersects the plane in 2 parts. Given n line already one additional line creates n+1 additional parts at most

=> $max_{sections}=(n+1)\cdot n/2 +1 $

For 6 lines this should be up to 22 parts